# correct way to implementing ienumerable<t> without code duplication

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

currently I have implemented it like below, but I dont like it because of the code duplication in GetEnumerator, how can i remove duplication...

```
public class EodSettlementRequestStubData : IEnumerable<SettlementRequest>
{

    public SettlementRequest UnapprovedFlows;
    public SettlementRequest UnapprovedRecovery;
    public SettlementRequest UnverifiedFlows;
    public SettlementRequest UnverifiedRecovery;

    IEnumerator<SettlementRequest> IEnumerable<SettlementRequest>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return UnapprovedFlows;
        yield return UnapprovedRecovery;
        yield return UnverifiedFlows;
        yield return UnverifiedRecovery;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return UnapprovedFlows;
        yield return UnapprovedRecovery;
        yield return UnverifiedFlows;
        yield return UnverifiedRecovery;
    }
}
```

I want to have ability to access it both as individually, as well as an IEnumerable to do some linq stuff...

I can create a list to avoid code duplication, but I feel there should be some better way to handle this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have the non generic version call the generic version (Also it is more "normal" to have the explictit interface version be the non generic `IEnumerable` instead of the generic `IEnumerable<T>`)

```
public class EodSettlementRequestStubData : IEnumerable<SettlementRequest>
{

    public SettlementRequest UnapprovedFlows;
    public SettlementRequest UnapprovedRecovery;
    public SettlementRequest UnverifiedFlows;
    public SettlementRequest UnverifiedRecovery;

    public IEnumerator<SettlementRequest> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return UnapprovedFlows;
        yield return UnapprovedRecovery;
        yield return UnverifiedFlows;
        yield return UnverifiedRecovery;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        //This is calling "IEnumerator<SettlementRequest> GetEnumerator()"
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: resharper by default created the non-generic one as public.. and that actually caused the problem.. thanks for the answer

Comment: @entre No it really doesn't.

Comment: @entre I also can confirm it does not. I use Resharper and it always makes the generic public. The only way it could happen is if you had it implement `IEnumerable` then later you told it to implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Scott you are absolutely right, I actually did that